# Prove $\| A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T\|_2 = 1$, when $rank (A)=n$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Given a matrix $A \in R^{m \times n}$, which is full ranked, prove $\| A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T\|_2 = 1$.
So my book already proved this by a nice geometrical approach.
But I wondered if we could use numerical methods to solve this.
I'm trying to use *QR* decomposition but well I couldn't proceed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quick exercise if we use the SVD. Write $A = U \Sigma V^T$, where $U$ is orthogonal of size $m$, $V$ is orthogonal of size $n$, and $\Sigma$ is the "diagonal" matrix
$$
\Sigma = \pmatrix{\Sigma_0 \\ 0_{(m-n)\times n}}, \quad \Sigma_0 = \pmatrix{\sigma_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && \sigma_m\\
}.
$$
Because $A$ has full rank, all $\sigma_i$ are non-zero. Verify that the matrix $M = A(A^TA)^{-1}A$ can be written as
$$
M = U \pmatrix{I_n&0\\ 0&0}U^T.
$$
Because $U$ and $U^T$ are orthogonal, this is in fact an SVD of $M$, which means that the singular values of $A$ are the diagonal entries of the diagonal matrix in the middle. From there, $\|M\|_2$ is the largest singular value of $M$, which is $1$.